# Knockout BindingHandlers with no required values

Tags: knockout.js

Is it possible to create a Knockout bindingHandler that has no required values?

```
ko.bindingHandlers['superAction'] = {
    init: function(...) { },
    update: function(...) { }
};
```

For example, the syntax might be:

```
<span data-bind="superAction"></span>
```

There is an optional value, so occasionally, it might be:

```
<span data-bind="superAction: myProperty"></span>
```

I've tried just a colon, no colon, .... They all cause run-time parsing exceptions.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible in any way other than altering knockout itself. Usually, bindings should be used for binding observable values to the view. "no parameter" is therefore not an option.

Comment: In a foreach, I was OK with the viewModel/data being readily available, and there really wasn't anything else needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible from knockout 3.0.
See https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/289.

Answer (score 3):

No, everything inside the `data-bind` attribute should be a valid javascript object literal if wrapped in curly braces. And `{ superAction }` is not.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to get confirmation that there wasn't some special handling available (or even some typical pattern for 'null'). I don't want to pass extra parameters if possible just to satisfy this, as they're redundant values.